# MySQL Update matched columns on all tables incrementally

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know an SQL Query that will update matched columns on all tables incrementally whether I set the first value or not.

```
Table A
`ACCOUNT_NO` = 10090
`ACCOUNT_NO` = 10091

Table B
`ACCOUNT_NO` = 10090
`ACCOUNT_NO` = 10091

Table C
`ACCOUNT_NO` = 10090
`ACCOUNT_NO` = 10091
```

Change to---

```
Table A
`ACCOUNT_NO` = 12090
`ACCOUNT_NO` = 12091

Table B
`ACCOUNT_NO` = 12090
`ACCOUNT_NO` = 12091

Table C
`ACCOUNT_NO` = 12090
`ACCOUNT_NO` = 12091
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "whether I set the first value or not."  Are you asking how to make an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column?

Comment: I'm going to update a lot of rows so I needed it to update like auto increment

for example I want to start the new value from 10001 the next would be 10002 and so on..

Thank you!

Comment: Are you doing an `UPDATE` or an `INSERT`?  I don't understand why you would want to increment the primary key on an `UPDATE` (or really, ever...).

Comment: I'm going to UPDATE those table, because I'm going to merge the newly updated data into our existing one. And I cannot merge it with the existing key value it will result into conflict that's why I want to change those value first.

Comment: Please edit your post with the query you have written

Answer (score 1):

If your ids are connected by foreign keys declared as `on update cascade` (see the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)), then you can update the values in the primary table and they will propagate to the other tables:

```
update a
    set account_no = account_no + 2000;
```

This, in turn, might generate errors, if new numbers conflict with old numbers.  There are ways around that if it occurs.

Having explained that, such an operation is *highly* suspicious.  There may be some very rare examples where this is necessary, but in general, primary keys should not be modified.  If a column is being modified, then it is an *attribute* of an entity, not an *identifier* for the entity.